# Fatal error with caret and RStudio

Tags: classification, rstudio, svm, r-caret

I am trying to test whether my data is linearly separable by testing my data using a linear SVM model vs. an RBF kernel model to see which score better between the two using F scores.

I am using the caret package and I have set up two models, `fit.SVMKernel` uses the 'rbf' method while `fit.SVML` uses 'svmLinear'.

I can run the entire length of my script down as far as the linear model and this executes without any issues but as soon as I run the kernel model I get a fatal error message and have to restart the session, see the attached image below.

Can anyone provide a suggestion as to why R crashes each time I run the kernel section of code?

Here is a reproducible version of my [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgkBr1CkDf7SUVNekFnVVNSSGM/view?usp=sharing) and my [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgkBr1CkDf7d0VNZ1ZaRlhyakE/view?usp=sharing) for anyone that gives two hoots!

[image]

I have loaded the caret package as per below

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Ireland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] kernlab_0.9-25  doMC_1.3.4      iterators_1.0.8 foreach_1.4.3   Amelia_1.7.4    Rcpp_0.12.9     dplyr_0.5.0     pROC_1.9.1      klaR_0.6-12    
[10] MASS_7.3-45     caret_6.0-73    ggplot2_2.2.1   lattice_0.20-34

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.3.2     nloptr_1.0.4       plyr_1.8.4         class_7.3-14       tools_3.3.2        digest_0.6.12      lme4_1.1-12        tibble_1.2        
 [9] nlme_3.1-128       gtable_0.2.0       mgcv_1.8-15        Matrix_1.2-7.1     DBI_0.5-1          SparseM_1.74       e1071_1.6-8        stringr_1.2.0     
[17] MatrixModels_0.4-1 stats4_3.3.2       combinat_0.0-8     grid_3.3.2         nnet_7.3-12        R6_2.2.0           foreign_0.8-67     minqa_1.2.4       
[25] reshape2_1.4.2     car_2.1-4          magrittr_1.5       scales_0.4.1       codetools_0.2-15   ModelMetrics_1.1.0 splines_3.3.2      assertthat_0.1    
[33] pbkrtest_0.4-6     colorspace_1.3-2   labeling_0.3       quantreg_5.29      stringi_1.1.2      lazyeval_0.2.0     munsell_0.4.3
```

The outcome variable I am trying to classify on (training.data.raw$Overshooting) is of type factor:

```
> str(training.data.raw)
'data.frame':   2846 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ Total.Tx.Height   : num  31.2 31.2 31.2 31.2 31.2 ...
 $ Antenna.Tilt      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 2 2 ...
 $ Antenna.Gain      : num  15.9 15.9 15.9 18.2 18.2 18.2 15.9 15.9 18.8 18.8 ...
 $ Ant.Vert.Beamwidth: num  10 10 10 4.4 4.4 4.4 9.6 9.6 4.3 4.3 ...
 $ RTWP              : num  -106 -104 -105 -105 -105 ...
 $ Voice.Drops       : int  1 12 1 0 1 5 1 18 4 3 ...
 $ Range             : num  11.33 5.14 5.14 11.33 3.88 ...
 $ Max.Distance      : num  12.43 6.24 6.24 12.43 4.98 ...
 $ Environment       : Factor w/ 3 levels "Rural","Suburban",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Rural             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Suburban          : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Urban             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Overshooting      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ OShooting         : Factor w/ 2 levels "Not.Overshooting",..: 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ HSUPA.Throughput  : num  164 223 232 241 264 ...
 $ Max.HSDPA.Users   : int  10 16 9 5 8 7 14 31 8 12 ...
 $ HS.DSCH.throughput: num  1975 2346 2995 3696 3894 ...
 $ Max.HSUPA.Users   : int  13 25 11 5 13 9 15 33 8 13 ...
 $ Avg.CQI           : num  16.2 18 19.4 19.7 21.8 ...
```

Below is the code I am using for the training control of both models:

```
metric <- "Accuracy"
train_Control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedCV", 
                                  number = 10, 
                                  repeats = 3),
                                  classProbs = T)
```

Here are the two models I have created `fit.SVMKernel` and `fit.SVMLinear`

```
set.seed(123)
fit.SVML <- train(Overshooting ~ Total.Tx.Height +
                  Antenna.Tilt +
                  Antenna.Gain +
                  Ant.Vert.Beamwidth +
                  RTWP +
                  Voice.Drops +
                  Range +
                  Max.Distance +
                  Rural +
                  Suburban +
                  Urban +
                  HSUPA.Throughput +
                  Max.HSDPA.Users +
                  HS.DSCH.throughput + 
                  Max.HSUPA.Users +
                  Avg.CQI, 
                data = training.data.raw,
                method = 'svmLinear',
                preProcess = c('center','scale'),
                trControl=train_Control,
                tuneLength=5,
                metric = metric)

set.seed(123)
fit.SVMKernel <- train(Overshooting ~ Total.Tx.Height +
                    Antenna.Tilt +
                    Antenna.Gain +
                    Ant.Vert.Beamwidth +
                    RTWP +
                    Voice.Drops +
                    Range +
                    Max.Distance +
                    Rural +
                    Suburban +
                    Urban +
                    HSUPA.Throughput +
                    Max.HSDPA.Users +
                    HS.DSCH.throughput + 
                    Max.HSUPA.Users +
                    Avg.CQI, 
                  data = training.data.raw,
                  method = 'rbf',
                  preProcess = c('center','scale'),
                  trControl=train_Control,
                  tuneLength=5,
                  metric = metric)#,
                  #summaryFunction=twoClassSummary)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the method I was calling for the model in train was not a valid model name. I changed this to one I knew worked any hey presto I was back in business.